# Highlight a cell if its copied to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that will copy values from one column on Sheet B to another column on another Sheet A. What I'd like to do is highlight the cells that were copied on Sheet B and highlight the cells in Sheet A that are not on Sheet B, essentially the inverse of the first part. On Sheet B only columns G and H would be highlighted but Sheet A could be from column A to H.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!G$3:G$7,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$D$3:$D$7=$A3)*(Sheet2!$B$3:‌​$B$7=$C3),),0)),G3)
```

Comment: Please post the code you have that performs the copy.  It shouldn't be hard to add a background color to cells that are copied.

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!G$3:G$7,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$D$3:$D$7=$A3)*(Sheet2!$B$3:$B$7=$C3),),0)),G3)

This code does work, I just need it to highlight the cell on the sheet copied from, not copied to.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up conditional formatting with the same logic to change the colour or either the cell that you are setting or the one that you are copying from.

Beware: this kind of code can make your spreadsheet very slow if over used.

So in one range (sheet 2) , you would have conditional formatting set up to highlight the cell if 
this match failed

```
MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$D$3:$D$7=$A3)*(Sheet2!$B$3:‌​$B$7=$C3),),0)
```

In the other range (sheet 1 a:h)

you would highlight if `ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!G$3:G$7,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$D$3:$D$7=$A3)*(Sheet2!$B$3:‌​$B$7=$C3),),0)))`
has picked the value from sheet2

I may have incorrectly butchered your code, but you should get the idea. Where you currently have a range of values, select the range, insert the conditional formatting, but edit the range to only check the first cell, it will automatically increment for you  (if you remove the appropriate $ signs)

[conditional formatting intro](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html)

Comment: When you say conditional format both arrays what do you mean by that?

Comment: I have modified the answer a bit. In sheet 1 a:h where data is copied to, select the range and set up conditional formatting. So that of the formula said to copy the data is true then format as green. Where as on sheet 2 you would select the range which is copied from but this time right a formula that indicates if the field would have been copied of true then colour 1 if false you can have a different colour

Comment: @RichardMartin How did you get on with highlighting the cells?